# Python syntax error on def sum(num1, num2)

Tags: python, syntax-error, function

I'm in a beginners programming class and I'm supposed to get this code working, I've typed it in exactly as the book says over and over and I'm getting an Invalid Syntax error and in Python Idle is highlights def in def sum(num1, num2)
I've looked everywhere, in the book, online and have yet to find an answer as to why it is giving me an error.

```
#this program uses the return value of a function

def main():
    #Get the user's age
    first_age = int(input('Enter your age: '))

    #Get the user's best friend's age.
    second_age = int(input("Enter your best friend's age: "))

    #Get the sum of both ages
    total = sum(first_age, second_age)

    #Display the total age
    print('Together you are', total, 'years old.')

#the sum function accepts two numeric arguments and
# return the sum of those arguments.
def sum(num1, num2):
    result = num1 + num2
    return result

#Call the main function

main()

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I just copy pasted this in to my editor and it ran successfully.

Comment: I emailed my class also and the one response I got said they copy and pasted the code and it worked perfectly for them.  I'm very frustrated and don't understand why I'm getting an error

Comment: Can you update your post with the exact error message? The entire message will help.

Comment: You're probably pasting that inside Idle's command prompt (this will cause a `SyntaxError`), instead of using File > New File...

Comment: Are you sure you're running Python 3?

Comment: Your code is running. Here's a thing to try to prove it. Save the file with a filename, like `myprog.py`. Go to a shell and run it from there: `python myprog.py`. Here's your output: `Enter your age: 10
Enter your best friend's age: 12
('Together you are', 22, 'years old.')`

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4.3.
I also tried using New File and running it, which also resulted in invalid syntax

Comment: There is more to that error message. Please paste the entire error message in your post.

Comment: Sorry I'm so new to this, I'm not sure what more there is to the message as all it shows me is the invalid syntax message

Comment: Tip: Don't use built-in function name as a custom function or a variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code runs. Have you the exact indentation like below? I have to fix some of it to make it work.

```
def main():
    #Get the user's age
    first_age = int(input('Enter your age: '))

    #Get the user's best friend's age.
    second_age = int(input("Enter your best friend's age: "))

    #Get the sum of both ages
    total = sum(first_age, second_age)

    #Display the total age
    print('Together you are', total, 'years old.')

#the sum function accepts two numeric arguments and
# return the sum of those arguments.
def sum(num1, num2):
    result = num1 + num2
    return result

#Call the main function

main()
```

Comment: that one works for me...
I had this same type of assignment last week and had no issues and this week no matter what I did nothing worked.
Thank you!

Comment: @user3539642 you a welcomed. Pay attention to indentation in python, if you gonna enjoy it. May be you a better off with another IDE, like pycharm community edition. its free and very good at checking for errors.